# Elasticsearch index does not recognize date (Logstash pipeline)

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, elastic-stack, elk, elasticsearch-7

I return with my doubts about elasticsearch.
I've been doing more testing and I'm almost done learning about ELK.
But I have a little problem. By creating a pipeline and outputting the elasticsearch cluster as follows:

```
output { 
  
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "IP:9200", "IP:9200", "IP:9200" ]
    manage_template => false
    index => "example-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

It does not correctly create the date. I have followed the indications of the documentation as it says: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index

The above code creates the index: `example-`

Instead if I leave the default by unchecking the fields `manage_template` and `index` it create the index with the format correct: `logstash-2020.08.17-000001`

So I don't really know what I'm failing at. If it is a documentation issue or some other formatting error.

Another detail is that I have seen some examples from 2018 with the following format: `index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"`. And reviewing the same previous link about the elasticsearch output plugin means creating different indexes, but I think it refers more to separating indexes according to a production or development space more than creating different indexes according to a date.

Comment: Can you show a sample document that gets indexed?

Comment: @Val the document are Apache logs, nothing special, just text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days I have noticed that I changed the default name of the field @timestamp
Now it works correctly. Thank you